# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded using R

Tags: rstudio

Running a script in RStudio where I attempt to write an output list in '.xlsx'.

The data is 79k rows x 12 columns.

I see the following message:

> Error in .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook") :
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

This is not a massive file, can someone suggest a solution please?

Comment: The most ugly, but quickest one is to do `export JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms512m -Xmx4G` and running `R`. Please note that `JAVA_OPTIONS` will affect all `JVMs` executed from the shell where `JAVA_OPTIONS` is set.

Comment: worked it out, your comment helps. Many thanks